# Do something after creating, and before destroying

Tags: ruby, datamapper

How can I have a block execute whenever an instance of a DataMapper class is a created, and another before it is destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by create & destroy you mean insert and remove from the db...

From the [documentation](http://datamapper.org/docs/callbacks.html)

```
 class Post
   include DataMapper::Resource

   # ... key and properties here

   # This record will save properly
   before :create do |post|
     true
   end

   # But it will not be destroyed
   before :destroy do |post|
     throw :halt
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to do it every time it is saved though

Comment: @Jeffrey, The before_create hook is only called when a record is first saved, not when it is updated.  So just replace "before :save" with "before :create" in @BarqueBobcat's example.